# keras training visualization using tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am using anaconda python3 with keras over tensorflow and would like to visualize the weights change, gradients and input images.

I read [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) in the keras docs about how to do it, when I try to use the following code in order to visualize the training I get only the loss and accuracy visualization without anything for the input data and weights and gradients.

```
tensorboard1 = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(time()),  write_grads=True, write_images=True, histogram_freq=1)
model.fit_generator(..., callbacks=[tensorboard1])
```

I read [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/) that in order to get visualization of the weights and gradients, I need to set the histogram_freq parameter of tensorboard to something other than the 0 default.

But When I try to do it I keep getting an error like explained [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4499) in this github issue

I am using keras 2.2.4 with anaconda, latest and updated. All of my other packaged are updated to conda latest

How can I get the images and gradients and weight visualization and workaround this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the actual errors you get, not point to a github issue. Are you doing multiple runs of the same model?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro what do you mean by multiple runs? I am running the script multiple times with multiple setups

Comment: Multiple runs would be training multiple models in the same script (or session). Please fully describe the problem and include source code.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I think i made some progress towards a solution, will further check and update soon

Comment: did u try `K.clear_session()` before each run? This should solve your problem.

Comment: @GergesDib yes i did

Comment: Usually this should do it, as long as it is place so that it clears all previous model's state.

Comment: @GergesDib now i get another error, even when clipping the gradients, i get nan value error when trying to write to tensorboard